# z-index not working with images

Tags: image, z-index, background-image, right-click

I am trying to make it so these images will line up the way so that the blank.gif will appear in front of the image. i cannot use it as a background image, and i have tried using a negative z-index like -1 but then the image disappears all together on the site i have tried to use it on. my goal is to make the gray and black image appears behind the blank.gif.

things that i have to avoid or will not work are these:

- z-index:**-1** (just the negative numbers)
- use of background image inside of a `<div>`

and both the images must remain inside a parent element, and my issue is that i cant use any script that needs to be inside of the head of the html. i have tried but cant find a solution. if you have any method of keeping an image from being right clicked and saved so easily then that would be great. any help is appreciated thank you.

image html are here: [index.html](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14413762/bbc/index.html)

code sample:

---

`<html><div style="position:absolute;width:150px;height:150px;display:inline;">
<img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14413762/blank.gif" style="position:static:width:150px;height:150px;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:2;"><img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14413762/bbc/image.png" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;;z-index:1;">
</div></html>`

Comment: You can't stop people from taking stuff you send to the browser. Plain and simple.

Comment: I find it infuriating when some website alters the right-click behavior of my mouse.  Don't do this.

Comment: yeah i don't like that either, that's why i was just looking to learn of different ways. i only want this code to work so i learn more but it doesn't look like anyone knows.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.. You're pretty much wasting time that is better spent elsewhere. A person who wants the image is going to get it, either with the web developer tools in firefox or chrome, viewing the page source, etc.

On a real note though, z-index only works with absolute, relative, or fixed positioned elements. It will not work with your statically positioned element that you set to a z-index of 2. I have done what you are trying to acheive with relatively positioned elements, z-index, and either top and left or negative top and left margins.

Comment: well more or less im looking basically to make the code work, not that i beleive that it will prevent people from taking it at all, im just looking to learn more. this code was tricky for me and all i wanted was some help. but instead all i have gotten is somebody's disapproval and doubt.

Comment: Hey chief, I was just trying to save you from wasted time if I could, if you read the second paragraph though -- I did actually provide an idea (your misuse of z-index with static positioning). Sorry to offend. Stress kills, remember that.